# Select attributes value in XML file using C# and LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

In this `XML` file, i would like to get all the *IDs* written in the `ID` attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <head>
    <datemaj>20140206-15-04-00</datemaj>
  </head>
  <PressReleases>
    <PressRelease id="545" version="1">
      <Name>Convert number to string</Name>
      <Date>20/05/1985</Date>
      <Input>1</Input>
      <Output>One</Output>
    </PressRelease>
    <PressRelease id="544" version="1">
      <Name>Find succeeding characters</Name>
      <Date>19/05/1985</Date>
      <Input>abc</Input>
      <Output>def</Output>
    </PressRelease>
    <PressRelease id="543" version="1">
      <Name>Convert multiple numbers to strings</Name>
      <Date>17/05/1985</Date>
      <Input>123</Input>
      <Output>One Two Three</Output>
    </PressRelease>
    <PressRelease id="542" version="1">
      <Name>Find correlated key</Name>
      <Date>02/05/1985</Date>
      <Input>a1</Input>
      <Output>b1</Output>
    </PressRelease>
    <PressRelease id="541" version="1">
      <Name>Count characters</Name>
      <Date>04/02/1985</Date>
      <Input>This is a test</Input>
      <Output>14</Output>
    </PressRelease>
    <PressRelease id="540" version="1">
      <Name>Another Test</Name>
      <Date>09/01/1985</Date>
      <Input>Test Input</Input>
      <Output>10</Output>
    </PressRelease>
  </PressReleases>
</root>
```

I tried this block of code , but **it returns nothing**:

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\ARNAUD\Documents\local\temp.xml");
        List<int> IDsInDistantXML = xdoc.Root.Elements("PressRelease")
                            .Select(pr => (int)pr.Attribute("id"))
                            .ToList();
```

PS: the `XML` file is correctly found.

Comment: `/root/PressReleases/PressRelease`

Comment: I'm curious, was (before my edit) it your actual *indentation/formatting* of original `XML` content? I found it bad for readability and error prone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Descendants`

```
 List<int> IDsInDistantXML = xdoc.Descendants("PressRelease")
                        .Select(pr => (int)pr.Attribute("id"))
                        .ToList();
```

The problem is your `PressRelease` element's are not direct child of your `root` element.So you get nothing, instead you can use:

```
xdoc.Root.Element("PressReleases").Elements("PressRelease")
```

Answer (score 2):

`PressRelease` nodes are child nodes of `PressReleases` which is child node of `root`

In this case you will need to change as follows:

```
List<int> IDsInDistantXML = xdoc.Root.Element("PressReleases")
                                     .Elements("PressRelease")
                                     .Select(pr => (int)pr.Attribute("id"))
                                     .ToList();
```